Issues with serverless-openapi-documenter Plugin in Serverless v4
I'm encountering an issue while using the serverless-openapi-documenter plugin in my AWS CodePipeline with Serverless v4. The error message I'm receiving is:
✖ str.join is not a function
TypeError: str.join is not a function
    at OpenAPIGenerator.log (/codebuild/output/src2007769175/src/node_modules/serverless-openapi-documenter/src/openAPIGenerator.js:102:38)
    at OpenAPIGenerator.generate (/codebuild/output/src2007769175/src/node_modules/serverless-openapi-documenter/src/openAPIGenerator.js:108:14)
    at PluginManager.runHooks (file:///root/.serverless/releases/4.0.38/package/dist/sf-core.js:1035:9296)
    at PluginManager.invoke (file:///root/.serverless/releases/4.0.38/package/dist/sf-core.js:1035:10067)
    at async PluginManager.run (file:///root/.serverless/releases/4.0.38/package/dist/sf-core.js:1035:10779)
    at async Serverless.run (file:///root/.serverless/releases/4.0.38/package/dist/sf-core.js:1042:10443)
    at async runFramework (file:///root/.serverless/releases/4.0.38/package/dist/sf-core.js:1065:3180)
    at async route (file:///root/.serverless/releases/4.0.38/package/dist/sf-core.js:1068:3074)
    at async Object.run2 [as run] (file:///root/.serverless/releases/4.0.38/package/dist/sf-core.js:1068:4620)
    at async Object.handler (file:///root/.serverless/releases/4.0.38/package/dist/sf-core.js:1068:9307)


I am trying to generate OpenAPI documentation for my Lambda function using Serverless Framework. Here is the relevant part of my serverless.yml configuration:
plugins:
  - serverless-openapi-documenter

functions:
  signin:
    handler: api/signin.handler
    timeout: 30
    runtime: python3.10
    memorySize: 2048
    package:
      patterns:
        - api/signin.py
      include:
        - helper/helpers.py
        - helper/common.py
    events:
      - http:
          path: /signin
          method: post
          cors: 
            origin: '*'
          documentation: ${file(serverless.doc.yml):endpoints.signin}


This is my buildspec.yml:
version: 0.2

env:
  parameter-store:
    SERVERLESS_ACCESS_KEY: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - npm install
      - npm install -g serverless
      - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${ACCESS_KEY}
      - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${SECRET_KEY}

  build:
    commands:
      - echo ${ENVIRONMENT}
      - serverless deploy --stage ${ENVIRONMENT}

  post_build:
    commands:
      - npm install -g widdershins
      - npm install -g serverless-openapi-documenter
      - serverless openapi generate -o openapi.yml
      - widdershins openapi.yml -o api-rme.md --language_tabs 'shell:Shell' --expandBody true --httpsnippet true --discovery true

artifacts:
  base-directory: $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/
  files:
    - 'api.md'


My questions are:
Is the serverless-openapi-documenter plugin compatible with Serverless v4?
How can I resolve the str.join is not a function error?
If serverless-openapi-documenter is not compatible, what alternative plugin can I use to generate OpenAPI documentation for my Lambda functions?
I have tried to change the version of the plugin, but this did not work for me
